# change directory to network drive in Cygwin

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hard-drive, backup, cygwin

I have a new wireless router in my home and have a 3 TB drive hooked up to it. I would like to write a backup script in cygwin which will copy over any changed files to the external HD.

For starters, how do I `cd` into the hard drive? In windows file explorer I simply type `//192.168.1.1` and it takes me to the network drive. However, when I type `cd //192.168.1.1` it does not work. So how can I change directory into the HD?

Secondly, does anyone have advice on how to write a good backup script to copy certain directories (recursively) if they have changed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can look at mounted drives in the cygwin UNIX environment's view of the underlying Windows OS by looking in `/cygdrive`.  Do a `df` at the cygwin shell prompt (usually `bash`) to see where the drives are mounted.  [Here's the documentation as to where mounted drives are found](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#cygdrive).  For instance, to change to the network drive mounted as Windows `f:\`, you'd `cd` to `/cygdrive/f`, as in:

```
$ cd /cydrive/f
```

Here's an example:

1. OS X Mavericks (UNIX) has a 3 TB drive mounted as `/Volumes/Time Machine`
2. A Virtual Windows XP (VM) is running on OS X, and sees `/Volumes/Time Machine` as `X:\`
3. Cygwin is running on the XP VM, and sees `/Volumes/Time Machine` as `/cygdrive/x` or even `x:`

> $ ls x:

Here's a picture:

[image]

If the external HD isn't currently mounted on the Windows host and already mapped to a mount point in `/cygdrive`, then you may need to mount the network share yourself.  [Take a look at cygwin's implementation of the UNIX `mount` command](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#mount).

**Another way to view the network folder is along the lines of the syntax which you used - I have my OS X server exporting my OS X login folder, whmcclos, as an SMB shared folder.**  I can set my current working directory to that shared folder from cygwin, on my Windows XP VM, running under OS X, as follows:

```
$ cd //192.168.0.2/whmcclos
```

That way, I don't even need to have the folder mounted as a drive letter to view it from within cygwin.

For backing up files that have changed, `rsync` will recursively backup only the files in a directory tree that have changed - it computes a minimal backup set, and only backs up what has changed, and has loads of options, including copying to network drives and being able to be used with encryption via `ssh`.  [Here's some hints as to using `rsync` with cygwin.](http://optics.ph.unimelb.edu.au/help/rsync/rsync_pc1.html)  Here is a command to compress and archive (recurse) source on drive mounted as `c:\`  and put in target on drive mounted as `f:\` on Windows host underlying cygwin.

```
$ rsync -avz /cygdrive/c/path/to/source /cygdrive/f/path/to/target
```

If you need any further assistance, please do leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks, I still have a question - when I used `-avz`, it does not correctly copy permissions. I get `rsync: failed to set permissions on "<path>": Permission denied (13)`. Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: It sounds like something I saw once with permissions, specifically with ACL permissions.  Look at the permissions including the ACL with `/bin/ls -le /path/to/source` and also `/bin/ls -le /path/to/target` to check out not only the various folder permissions, but the ACL permissions of and in those folders.  See `man ls` and the `-le` switches and `man chmod` and the `+a` and `-a` switches.  I'm 99% certain that it has something to do with permissions.  Start with rsync'ing a subset of the source tree to say, `/tmp`, where you know you have write permission, and see how that works.

Comment: [Network drives may not show up under `/cygdrive/` when running Cygwin with Administrator permissions](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-xfree/2011-08/msg00056.html). [Microsoft provides a solution for these situations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(WS.10).aspx).